# How to express three cases with the conditional operator?

Tags: c++, c, conditional-operator

Is it possible to express the cases using the conditional operator? For Example :

```
 if(rval==1)
     DO THIS 1;
 else if(rval==2)
     DO THIS 2;
 else if (rval ==3)
     DO THIS 3;
```

Comment: The ternary operator is intended for conditional *expressions*, not for control flow

Comment: why do you not use switch-case?

Comment: Don't do this.At best this is going to just be unreadable and error prone.

Comment: ideally you would not want to implement the logic using ternary operator, but it can be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. What you have there looks like a use-case for a `switch`-statement:

```
switch(rval) {
    case -1: DO THIS 1; break;
    case  2: DO THIS 2; break;
    case  3: DO THIS 3; break;
    default: ERROR;
}
```

**Edit** I was over-eager here. As [@Luchian Grigore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673730/luchian-grigore) points out in the comments, you can do this (as he demonstrates in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8516597/160206)). Note that this is also well defined for cases where one or both expressions are of the type `void`, as specified in §5.16/2 [expr.cond]:

> If either the second or the third operand has type (possibly
>   cv-qualified) void, then the lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer
>   (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are
>   performed on the second and third operands, and one of the following
>   shall hold:
>
> — The second or the third operand (but not both) is a
>   throw-expression (15.1); the result is of the type of the other and is
>   an rvalue.
>
> — Both the second and the third operands have type void;
>   the result is of type void and is an rvalue.
>
> [Note: this includes the
>   case where both operands are throw-expressions. ]

Comment: Can you provide a link to the standard that says you can't?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I can't - you got me there. But I am not sure how to run arbitrary stuff (as the OP suggested in his question) using the conditional operator. What would happen if the `expression` in your solution is a `void`-function?

Comment: I actually did test it with a void function... and it works... it doesn't have to return anything. It can be used exactly as an if statement, except you can't have code blocks, only expressions. Try it out.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Can you produce a standard-quote that proves that this is not undefined behavior?

Comment: I asked for the same thing of you.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it does matter actually. I agree with Bjorn that it could just be working on my compiler. See section 5.16 - the second and third operands are expressions; section 5.16.2 deals with expressions that have type void. So there...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you're not getting the point. Also, if you had bothered to look beforehand, you'd have seen that you gave the exact same answer as me :|

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: You are right, it is indeed allowed and well defined.

Comment: +1 also, pls tell me how you do your copying from the standard. I hate having to write the quotes by hand :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: It is really just copy/paste from the pdf and then some formatting by hand.

Comment: "You are right, it is indeed allowed and well defined." -- I have trouble understanding why any even moderately experienced C programmer would think otherwise. Note that void expressions are allowed (and frequently used) as statements; it would be pointlessly restrictive not to allow them as the operands of `?:`.

Comment: @Luchian: try a different PDF reader, maybe? And note that the default in PDF readers sometimes is that click follows links but doesn't select text, you might have to select a "text highlighting tool" or something @all: note that there *is* another restriction here, the expressions need to be convertible to a common type. So in some cases you might find yourself writing `(rval == 1) ? (void) dothis1() : (rval == 2) ? (void) dothis2() : (void) dothis3();`, and probably you will wonder why you aren't using a switch statement.

Answer (score 6):

Although this isn't the usual use for the ternary operator, this is how you do it:

```
( rval == 1 ) ? (expression1) : 
( rval == 2 ) ? (expression2) : 
( rval == 3 ) ? (expression3) : (default);
```

However, for the sake of code readability, I suggest you stick to the `if` statements.

Or better yet, it seems a `switch` would be even more appropriate here.

EDIT:

This is the code I used for the test:

```
void foo() {};
void goo() {}

int main()
{
   int x = 0;
   x == 0  ? foo() : x == 1 ? goo() : foo();
}
```

EDIT2:

For all nay-sayers - see section `5.16` - the second and third operands are expressions; section `5.16.2` deals with expressions that have type void.

Comment: Actually, I think your first example should be a more or less standard idiom.  Provided it's formatted in a way that makes it obvious what is going on.  As you did, for example.  I use it when appropriate, and I'd like to think that others would be familiar enough with it to recognize it; a `return` with something like this is IMHO much more readable than a mess of `if`s, with a return in each branch.

Comment: great Luchian!!

Answer (score 0):

```
int lval = (rval==-1) ? 1 : ( (rval==2) ? 2 : 3 );
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the standard that says you can't?

Comment: I meant 'DO THIS' has to be an expression (which returns a value). It can't be just any block of code. Is that not right?

Comment: You should specify this in the answer, because indeed you **can** do this for an expression.

Comment: "Is that not right?" -- No, it's not right ... the expression can be void; it need not return a value.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int rval = 2;

    (rval==-1)? (printf("-1")) :( ((rval==2) ?(printf("2")) : ((rval ==3) ? (printf("3")) : (1)) ));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Jim: take the above source code into VS C++ and it works very well.

Comment: No, i am sorry, it did work well even then apart from the ;. This is even implied by the comment you put to another post here.Just do not take it so big. It's not a life - death decision.

Comment: You are a big words person who is missing the big picture. What is the purpose of the answer i gave? Wasn't it to help? Even if there was a typo, it can be fixed and no reasonable person would jump on personal attacks but rather try to advise how to fix. Just chill out.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(rval == 1 ? DoThis1() : (rval == 2 ? DoThis2() : (rval == 3 ? DoThis3() : /*do nothing*/)))
{
    // The if-body.
}
```

But I think using the if-statment or the switch statment is more better

Comment: That isn't valid C (although it isn't quite as bad as Jiri Pik's version that contains semicolons).

Answer (score 0):

That would look ugly, and defies every coding standard I've seen.  Nevertheless, it would look like this:

```
int rval;
int foo = rval == -1 ? DoThis1() : (rval == 2 ? DoThis2() : DoThis3());
```

I'm assuming that rval == 3 is the only other possible option.  And if that assumption is wrong, it makes this whole mess that much more a statement of DON'T DO THIS!!!

Comment: What if the DoThis functions return void ?

Comment: @Paul: ...then it won't work.  But I"m trying to stay as close to the confines of his request as possible.

Comment: Not "don't do this".  Just format it nicely, so that it's clear what you're doing.  Like Lucien Grigor did, or with all of the `?` and `:` at the start of a new line, appropriately indented.  (And without the unnecessary parentheses: `c1 ? x1 : c2 ? x2 ...` is the equivalent of `if...else if...`.)

Comment: @Paul, Brent The OP did not ask to return a value ... it works fine if the functions return void and the value isn't used. See Luchian Grigore's considerably superior answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch ( rval ) {
  case 1 : 
    // Process for rval = 1
    ...
    break;
  case 2 : 
    // Process for rval = 2
    ...
    break;
  case 3 :
    // Process for rval = 3
    ... 
  default : 
    throw new InvalidStateException()
    // Process for all other cases.
    ...
}
```

Comment: `throw new InvalidStateException()` -- in C++? It not usually clever to dynamically allocate exceptions and then throw a pointer to them, you should throw an exception object.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
    void MySwitch(int rval)
    {
             (rval==-1) ? DoThis(-1),0 :
            ((rval==2) ? DoThis(2),0 :
            ((rval==3) ? DoThis(3),0 : 0));
    }
```

Full Example:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void DoThis(int j)
    {
     printf("DoThis(%d)\n", j);
    }

    void MySwitch(int rval)
    {
             (rval==-1) ? DoThis(-1),0 :
            ((rval==2) ? DoThis(2),0 :
            ((rval==3) ? DoThis(3),0 : 0));
    }

    int main(void)
    {
     printf("Calling MySwitch(-1)\n");
     MySwitch(-1);
     printf("Calling MySwitch(2)\n");
     MySwitch(2);
     printf("Calling MySwitch(3)\n");
     MySwitch(3);
     printf("Calling MySwitch(4)\n");
     MySwitch(4);
    }
```

Output:

```
Calling MySwitch(-1)
DoThis(-1)
Calling MySwitch(2)
DoThis(2)
Calling MySwitch(3)
DoThis(3)
Calling MySwitch(4)
```

Of course, this is silly. Don't ever do this.

Comment: The `0`'s aren't needed ... `void` is a valid type for `?:` and its expressions.

Comment: I should add that the last one is needed, e.g., `(rval==-1) ? DoThis(-1) :
            ((rval==2) ? DoThis(2) :
            ((rval==3) ? DoThis(3) : (void)0))`

Answer (score 0):

There are many cases indeed when you need to use an expression (e.g., in a macro expanded where an expression is expected).

They're all valid, and when used wisely will improve the readability.

It is a shame that this distinction between statements and expressions exist (it is very unnatural and was not present in Algol, a grandfather of all the modern imperative structural languages), but there are non-standard extensions to leverage such an injustice: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs

So, an answer to your question, using this extension, would be the following:

`rval==1?({DO-THIS}):(?rval==2:({...}):...)`

But make sure that the last statement of `DO-THIS` is always an expression yielding a value.